# different trendline types for each group in the same plot with gglpot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below dataset :

```
ID        LAND         nifH        AOA  
1   agricultural    2272430.26  36942400.00  
2   agricultural    2371496.98  34871000.00  
3   agricultural    1506827.26  28344300.00  
4   agricultural    3072303.99  37818300.00  
5   agricultural    822133.30   17915800.00  
6   agricultural    1323219.76  25076900.00  
7   agricultural    2832007.75  12980100.00  
8   agricultural    1642144.16  66015700.00  
9   agricultural    1917801.37  30374200.00  
10  agricultural    1091955.01  24029000.00  
11  agricultural    541873.86   7077250.00  
12  agricultural    965444.92   15828000.00  
13  agricultural    2274418.90  2768740.00  
14  agricultural    503230.31   5417750.00  
15  agricultural    1134978.51  29983100.00  
16  agricultural    1138200.48  33578500.00  
17  agricultural    2599519.18  38748600.00  
18  agricultural    830130.41   19844300.00  
19  agricultural    1718543.20  39919100.00  
20  agricultural    848999.15   31510400.00  
21  agricultural    993265.16   19315900.00  
22  agricultural    1328374.95  8704000.00  
23  agricultural    588577.99   7107390.00  
24  natural 1265534.76  11633500.00  
25  natural 1424244.23  22986800.00  
26  natural 1645932.48  74835300.00  
27  natural 794645.31   53313900.00  
28  natural 1206666.73  57958200.00  
29  natural 1194033.93  56863100.00  
30  natural 1647612.35  76749100.00  
31  natural 1373078.78  78014900.00  
32  natural 2588474.53  95331700.00  
33  natural 1709596.00  49901500.00  
34  natural 2185120.45  82679000.00  
35  natural 1614733.98  21855400.00  
36  natural 1304585.38  49941000.00  
37  agricultural    699308.20   1609450.00  
38  agricultural    443499.88   776379.06  
39  natural 501543.10   49777.59  
40  natural 83694.81    9711.16  
41  agricultural    1545325.46  13227000.00  
42  agricultural    853717.25   851032.11  
43  natural 592806.33   731260.03  
44  agricultural    274198.19   30947.01  
45  agricultural    660950.13   76135400.00  
46  agricultural    731145.76   4326470.00  
47  agricultural    946266.70   1808130.00  
48  agricultural    1262565.09  648326.92  
49  agricultural    869847.46   16870500.00  
50  agricultural    1325450.54  78977500.00
```

I used the below code to make a scatterplot between AOA and NIRK and grouped them by LAND

```
p=ggplot(all_data_untransformed, aes(x = NIRK, y = AOA, colour = factor(LAND))) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "glm", family = gaussian, se = T)
```

Is there a way to perform different smooth method for each group (e.g. apply a gam model for group A and a lm model for group B) and also to add to the plot the R sqt for each trendline?
Thank you

Comment: Of course there is. There are many options available for `stat_smooth`, check these out, namely `method` and `family`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Maybe I was not very spesific in  my question. I want for example to apply a gam model for group A and a lm model for group B, is there a way to do that? I think that    stat_smooth    applies the same trendline method to both groups.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then please add this requirement into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have different models for different levels, one solution is to use two calls of the `stat_smooth()` and then subset data for each model.

```
ggplot(all_data_untransformed, aes(x = nifH, y = AOA, colour =LAND)) + 
      geom_point() +
      stat_smooth(data=subset(all_data_untransformed,LAND=="agricultural"),
                                  method = "lm", se = T) +
      stat_smooth(data=subset(all_data_untransformed,LAND=="natural"),
                                method = "loess", se = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I believe    subset    is what I was looking for!